# Remove newlines in quoted string

Tags: php, regex, string, newline

In PHP, I am processing strings between double-quotes, where I have no control over how those strings are generated. Somehow, at some point, newlines appear at the end of some of the strings. It results into something like this:

```
"This is a value"
"I'm another string!"
"I somehow have a newline at the end
"
"Okay, this is the last one.."
```

How can I best remove these newlines if I were to iteratively loop through all of these strings?

I can imagine I should use `preg_replace`, but I don't know what is the best pattern to get rid of the newlines at the end of a quoted string.

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: Should be something like this: `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+"$/, '"', $string);`

Comment: @Narf: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain this one? Is it like, any newline character, 1 or more, before a double quote? And replace the match with a double quote?

Comment: Basically yes, but technically it replaces with a double quote any number of return carriages and/or newline characters that are followed by a double quote AND that double quote must be the last character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
  $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

will do the job

Comment: how it does the job?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is this like replacing any kind white-space with a space, and trim the leading and trailing spaces? That is clever.